# How do you do a partial string match in PostgreSQL in a language-independent fashion?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, internationalization

I'm working on an application backed by PostgreSQL which has an API that makes queries using `ILIKE`: `SELECT xyz FROM abc WHERE name ILIKE 'nomnomnom%'`, where `'nomnomnom'` is a (parameterized) input from the user for an autocomplete list. This works well enough for English (and other languages that use Latin characters).

However, I need to be able to get the autocomplete function to work, independent of the language the stored names are in. Would the above query work with, say, Arabic, Chinese, or Cyrillic?

Comment: It should work as long as your db encoding supports those character sets and the input string has the same encoding. Are you having troubles?

Comment: yeah. it should just work, UTF-8 supports right-to-left languages in natural order. so long as your forms and middleware also handle it correctly there will be no problem with postgresql.